# SQL INNER JOIN multiple tables not working as expected

Tags: sql, database, join, inner-join

I'm trying to have a better understanding of JOIN or INNER JOIN multiple tables in a SQL database.

Here is what I have:

SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM csCIDPull
INNER JOIN CustomerData ON CustomerData.CustomerID = csCIDPull.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN EMSData ON EMSData.EmsID = csCIDPull.EmsID
;
```

This returns NO results, if I remove the `INNER JOIN EMSData` section, it provides the info from `CustomerData` and `csCIDPull` tables. My method of thinking may be incorrect. I have let's say 5 tables all with a int ID, those ID's are also submitting to a single table to combine all tables (the MAIN table contains only ID's while the other tables contain the data).

Figured I'd shoot you folks posting to see what I might be doing wrong.  -Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it sounds like you don't have matching data in your EMSData table.  You would need to use an `OUTER JOIN` for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM csusaCIDPull
    LEFT JOIN CustomerData ON CustomerData.CustomerID = csCIDPull.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN EMSData ON EMSData.EmsID = csCIDPull.EmsID
```

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

*Side note: consider not returning `*` but rather select the fields you want from each table.*

Comment: LEFT JOIN works well.   I am still playing around a little, the Visual Explanation of SQL Joins you provided is very helpful.  In my QUERY I just used the * for testing in my code, the SELECT is setup with specific cells in my code.

Comment: Everything should have had data, comes to find out, EMS only had 3 rows while CustomerData had 7(forgotten testing), corrected the test db CustomerData Table and it works flawless.    Thanks again for the insight.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Check this about the SQL joins

Answer (score 0):

It's too much to cover outer join vs inner join in this answer, but I would start by studying the difference between the two:

Here's a brief starter:

The inner join requires that you have data that satisfies the join criteria. If you for some reason don't have any records in EMSData and csCIDPull with a common EmsID - no records will be returned at all. If that's the case, you should consider using an outer join instead if you still want records from CustomerData to be returned independently of the EMDData join